# Translate matrix algebra code from VB to R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

For a project, I am trying to replicate/rewrite the following Visual Basic code from a case study so I can run it in R.

```vb
For j=1 to N
    For I=1 to M
        While I>j
            If b(I,j) c=P then
                a(I,j)=l else
                if b(1, j)<= [P+ (l-P ) /21 then
                    a(I,j)=3 else
                    a(1, j)=O
                end if
            end if
        wend
        while Icj
            if a(I,j)=l then
                a(j,i)=l else
                if a(I,j)=3 then
                    a(j,I)=O else
                    a( j ,I) =3
                end if
             end if
        wend
    next
next
```

The goal is to compare the values b(j,I) from matrix B(M,N) and fill matrix A(M,N) with either 0,1 or 3. It should represent the results of a football game.

This is what I got so far:

```r
M <- 3
N <- 3

A <- matrix(0,M,N)

B <- matrix(sample(0:4,25, replace=TRUE),nrow=M, ncol=N)

for (i in 1:nrow(B)) {
for (j in 1:ncol(B)) {
  while (i > j) {
    if (B[i,j] > B[j,i]) {
      A[i,j] = 3 & A[j,i] = 0
    }
    if (B[i,j] < B[j,i]) {
      A[i,j] = 0 & A[j,i] = 3
    }
    else {
      A[i,j] = 1 & A[j,i] = 1
    }
  }
    }
      }
```

I would really appreciate any help or tips!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  StackOverflow is a problem solving service, not a code writing service.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Questions like yours are most likely to get a respone if you demonstrate reasonable effort yourself: what have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?  You also need to supply sample input data and your expected output.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question to indent the VB code (using https://www.vbindent.com/). My rationale was not to force you into any particular style of indentation, but many (including me) find that a reasonable indentation style makes understanding the flow and structure of code much easier. (And I fixed a small typo, an inclusion of `-` that was foiling an `end if`.) Feel free to rollback if you don't like it, in which case *my apologies*.

Comment: The VB code, as it currently stands, contains syntax errors, and is therefore hard to translate.